# How to apply git diff --binary patches without git installed?

Tags: linux, git, deployment, diff, patch

I use to git diff to generate patches that can be applied to remote server to update a project.

Locally, I run:

```
git diff --no-prefix HEAD~1 HEAD > example.patch
```

Upload example.patch to remote server and run:

```
patch --dry-run -p0 < example.patch
```

If dry-run is successful, I run:

```
patch -p0 < example.patch
```

This works well, except when diff includes binary files. Today, I found that I can use:

```
git diff --no-prefix --binary HEAD~1 HEAD > example.patch
```

The problem is that the generated patch file can not be applied using patch.

How can I apply these binary patch files without having git installed the server?

I would like to maintain ability to use dry-run.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For an outlandish answer, what you could do is use [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) to mount the remote system upon where ever you do have git, and then run your commands that way.  Approach the problem from a different frame of reference:  Instead of wondering how to run commands where the tool is not, why not create an environment where the data comes to your tool ( via sshfs ? )

Comment: that's not bad actually. very very not bad. I like it

Comment: the only concern is that it might be a little slow for big patches(but that should not happen if you're deploying a lot of small patches) Also, what if there is a connection problem while you're applying a patch?

Comment: @TarasMankovski There is a bigger problem when applying git binary delta patch to big binary file(s).

Answer (score 2):

In many situations and in this too, you can't create data with more advanced tool and use it with less advanced. It's a happy coincidence that `patch` works for non-binary git-diffs. `git diff` introduces an extension to standard diff.

To achieve the goal, you can:

- install git on the destination system (that's the best approach, really)
- mount destination system to local, as chiggsy says
- just `scp`/`rsync` new files. Not bad for small ones.

Comment: Hey Temoto, thank you for the answer, but I am looking for an answer that I don't already know.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the change log](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/patch.git/tree/ChangeLog), we can expect patch versions > 2.6.1 to support GIT binary diffs.

Comment: patch 2.7.5 still doesn't on my system :(

Comment: The Changelog at http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/patch.git/tree/NEWS doesn't seem to mention this either...

Comment: Actually it doesn't. And there is no sign of other patch(1) supports git binary diff at the moment.

Answer (score -7):

Use this

```
git apply example.patch
git add --patch
git commit
```

You can omit --patch flag, but you won't see every change and check patching process.

Comment: OK, I didn't get it exactly first.

So if you have no Git on remote server, the only way is to copy modified binary files. As far as I know, 'patch' does not support binary diffs.

Comment: yes, standard patch does not support binary diffs, but git diff can generate binary patches. I would like to apply them without having git installed on remote server.